# How to correctly create a SynchronizedStack class?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I made a simple synchronized Stack object in Java, just for training purposes.
Here is what I did:

```
public class SynchronizedStack {
    private ArrayDeque<Integer> stack;

    public SynchronizedStack(){
        this.stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();     
    }

    public synchronized Integer pop(){
        return this.stack.pop();
    }

    public synchronized int forcePop(){
        while(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("    Stack is empty");
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return this.stack.pop();
    }

    public synchronized void push(int i){
        this.stack.push(i);
        notifyAll();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return this.stack.isEmpty();
    }

    public synchronized void pushAll(int[] d){
        for(int i = 0; i < d.length; i++){
            this.stack.push(i);
        }
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized String toString(){
        String s = "[";
        Iterator<Integer> it = this.stack.iterator();   
        while(it.hasNext()){
            s += it.next() + ", ";
        }
        s += "]";
        return s;
    }
}
```

Here are my questions:

- Is it OK not to synchronize the `isEmtpy()` method? I figured it was because even if another Thread is modifying the stack at the same time, it would still return a coherent result (there is no operation that goes into a isEmpty state that is neither initial or final). Or is it a better design to have all the methods of a synchronized object synchronized?
- I don't like the `forcePop()` method. I just wanted to create a thread that was able to wait until an item was pushed into the stack before poping an element, and I thought the best option was to do the loop with the `wait()` in the `run()` method of the thread, but I can't because it throws an `IllegalMonitorStatException`. What is the proper method to do something like this?
- Any other comment/suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't lock methods, prefer to lock on objects. Read this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: Stack extends Vector, which is already synchronized.  A different choice of collection might be better for this training exercise.

Comment: Don Roby: Yes, as pointed out by axtavt, I am now using ArrayDeque.

Comment: Sean Patrick Floyd: So you say it is better to do this:
public void pop(){synchronized(this.stack){return this.stack.pop();}}
than this: public void synchronized pop(){return this.stack.pop();} ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- `Stack` itself is already synchronized, so it doesn't make sense to apply synchronization again (use `ArrayDeque` if you want a non-synchronized stack implementation)
- It's NOT OK (aside from the fact from the previous point), because lack of synchronization may cause memory visibility effects.
- `forcePop()` is pretty good. Though it should pass `InterruptedException` without catching it to follow the contract of interruptable blocking method. It would allow you to interrupt a thread blocked at `forcePop()` call by calling `Thread.interrupt()`.

Comment: Suppose I had coded this without relying on the Stack/ArrayDeque implementation, but just with arrays in a way that I am sure there is no transitive state that could cause incoherent isEmpty() results. Would it be better not to synchronize it (faster) or to synchronize it anyway (safer)?

Comment: Synchronize it anyway - the problem is that, without some synchronization, you might -never- see the updates from another thread in your isEmpty() call.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with not synchronizing `isEmpty()` is that you don't know what's happening underneath. While your reasoning is, well, reasonable, it assumes that the underlying `Stack` is also behaving in a reasonable manner. Which it probably is in this case, but you can't rely on it in general.

And the second part of your question, there's nothing wrong with a blocking pop operation, see [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for a complete implementation of all the possible strategies.

And one other suggestion: if you're creating a class that is likely to be re-used in several parts of an application (or even several applications), don't use `synchronized` methods. Do this instead:

```
public class Whatever {
  private Object lock = new Object();

  public void doSomething() {
    synchronized( lock ) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

The reason for this is that you don't really know if users of your class want to synchronize on your `Whatever` instances or not. If they do, they might interfere with the operation of the class itself. This way you've got your very own private lock which nobody can interfere with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `stack.isEmpty()` won't need synchronization might be true, but you are relying on an implementation detail of a class that you have no control over.
The javadocs of Stack state that the class is not thread-safe, so you should synchronize all access.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing idioms a little.  You are backing your `SynchronizedStack` with `java.util.Stack`, which in turn is backed by `java.util.Vector`, which is `synchronized`.  I think you should encapsulate the `wait()` and `notify()` behaivor in another class.